# Picturebox Bitmap Scaling

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `Picturebox` and a ton of `Bitmaps` that can be displayed in it. The relative size of the Bitmap when compared to the others is of importance to the user. They need to be able to see that one image is smaller or bigger than another. The Bitmap must also fit in the picturebox entirely and the picturebox cannot be resized.

When simply displaying the Bitmaps unscaled in a huge picturebox the relative sizes of the bitmaps is easy to see, but when trying to fit them in a small box and having to scale them down my problem starts.

When using the Stretch `PictureBoxSizeMode` as you would imagine the images sometimes appear distorted due to the nonspecific sizes of the Bitmaps and the fact they then get stretched to fill the whole box regardless, but the Stretch sizemod is the closest to the kind I need.

None of the other sizemodes suit my needs so I know now I need to create a function to resize the Bitmap and here was the start of my attempt until I realized I was going in **completely** the wrong direction, the image returned here retains no 'scale'.

```
    private Bitmap ResizeBitmap(Bitmap img)
    {
        int newWidth = 0;
        int newHeight = 0;
        double imgRatio;

        if (img.Width > img.Height)
        {
            imgRatio = ((double)img.Height / (double)img.Width) * 100;

            newWidth = pictureBox.Width;

            newHeight = (int)(((double)newWidth / 100) * imgRatio);
        }
        else
        {
            imgRatio = ((double)img.Width / (double)img.Height) * 100;

            newHeight = pictureBox.Height;

            newWidth = (int)(((double)newHeight / 100) * imgRatio);
        }

        Bitmap newImg = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);

        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(newImg))
            g.DrawImage(img, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);

        return newImg;
    }
```

I've been staring at the screen for a while now and the math to do the scaling currently eludes me, I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction. It's almost 4am so maybe my brain just isn't grasping some simple concepts.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Set the PictureBoxSizeMode to [Zoom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.pictureboxsizemode.aspx). This maintains the aspect ratio.

Comment: As said I've tried all of the SizeModes, Zoom still makes a tiny Bitmap fill the whole Picturebox just the same as a big one.

Comment: OK, but it doesn't distort the image, right? Do you want to maintain the relative sizes of the bitmaps? So the smallest should only be scaled by the same amount as the largest?

Comment: Yes, that sounds about right, I guess I'd can't do this on a per Bitmap basis then, I'd need to take into account all other Bitmaps?

Comment: Yup, sounds like it. I'd go through all bitmaps once and find the one that requires the smallest scale factor, then use that scale factor no matter which bitmap is being viewed.

Comment: Yep that defiantly sounds like the way to do it now I think about it. Feel free to edit your answer or not, either way I'll mark it as accepted. Thanks for the help.