# C# Resize image from webclient

Tags: c#, image, resize

I have a program that sets the image from a link , to a picture box.

For example:

pictureBox1.Load("http://www.e357.net/wordpress/beingernest/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/questionmark-150x150.jpg");

But since the pictureBox size is 100x100, the image gets cut down.

How can i resize the image, without changing the pictureBox size?

Im using WinForms.

Thanks.

Comment: Please do some research before asking these questions. Please put your code here. try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195064/fastest-image-resizing-in-net

Comment: Get the picture first and resize according to your needs and then Load on Picturebox.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Picturebox Bitmap Scaling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14207895/picturebox-bitmap-scaling)

Comment: Abhishek, that's what i dont know how to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just change your `pictureBox1.SizeMode` to achieve that behavior.

In your case

```
pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
```

and

```
pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
```

should work.